# URL Rewriting: index.html is found but then doesn't find css file

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

To begin with, I have to say that my index.html file normally finds the css folder.

So this is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/id([0-9]+)$ index.html [L]
```

As you can see, if I e.g. type in [website domain]/index/id7, it loads the index.html file as it should. But then the server proceeds to search in **/index/**. Of course, it doesn't find my css files there. I don't even have an index folder, it just creates one and searches for a css folder there:

[image: the css files is empty]

**How can I make it search for my css folder in my DocumentRoot, as if index.html would have normally been called?**

Comment: You should be using either root-relative or absolute URLs to your static resources, not relative URL-paths as I suspect you are using. It is the browser that searches in the "/index" folder (URL-path segment) not the server. The browser needs to resolve the relative URL-path.

Comment: please share your html file.  At least the head portion